# How to create native control in Qt?

Tags: qt, widget, native

Maybe, someone knows where you can read about creating qt-widgets, based on platform’s native controls? And where I can find information (examples) about using QWidget::create() method?

Comment: Maybe you can create a QWidget instance, call its `winId()` and use native API to add native control to this widget.

Comment: Short answer: You cannot. Qt does not use native controls, nor can it embed native controls into its windowing infrastructure. If you want native controls you do not want Qt. In fact, if you want native controls, **anything** is better than Qt, even MFC. Have a look at [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/) for example - another cross platform GUI framework, that does in fact use native controls.